# Virtualization engine not found. Plugin loading aborted

Tags: java, android, android-studio, intellij-idea, genymotion

Basically, today I switched computers, making me have to install genymotion again. I faced a problem, which I remember I had faced a year ago, but I had forgot what to do. Here's what I did:

**First, I just downloaded genymotion:**
[image]

Then, after the setup process, when I oppened genymotion from the application folder, I got this message:

[image]

After some hours, I figured out how to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

So basically, I just needed to install virtual box. Once I opened it, I had to create a new virtual device:

[image]

Then, I simply quit genymotion with **Command Q**, or on windows just press X. Then, when I re opened genymotion, the error was gone.